# can we call AIDL From remote device

Tags: android, aidl

Can i call client AIDL interface from another device. And If yes how? If No then what is exact use of AIDL in android
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Regards
Sumit

Comment: I would look into the iBinder framework. I assume it would have to go through FCM (previously GCM) as a portal.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i call client AIDL interface from another device

No.

> what is exact use of AIDL in android

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html), "It allows you to define the programming interface that both the client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other using interprocess communication (IPC)." As an app developer, primarily you use it when implementing the binding pattern for services (e.g., `bindService()`, `onBind()`) between apps.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare